# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Python 3.4.2

Tags: updates, python

Is it possible update default Python 3.4 to 3.4.2? How?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Download the 3.4.2 source files from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Extract it to a temporary directory within your `Downloads` folder
3. Open a terminal session.
4. Navigate to the folder with `cd ~/Downloads/Python-3.4.2`
5. As per the Python documentation, run the following commands from the terminal:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   make test
   sudo make install
   ```

This will upgrade your existing Python-3.4 installation to Python-3.4.2 (accessible as `python3`)

Comment: Do not to forget to: `sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4` before `make install` or `pyenv install`, or you will be missing built-in modules like readline, sqlite3, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use pyenv as your python manager. [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)

It will allow you to install any version of python, pypy, python3, stackless etc.

it uses shims and also has a nice plugin for virtualenv which makes it a very easy option to use [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv)

Very simple installation.

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

find out which versions are available to install

```
$ pyenv install --list
```

install python 3.4.2

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/scripts$ pyenv install 3.4.2
Downloading Python-3.4.2.tgz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.2/Python-3.4.2.tgz 
Installing Python-3.4.2...
```

Comment: The package `pyenv` doesn't seem to be in the repository...

Comment: @MarioS.E. you install it into your home directory: http://opencafe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/pyenv/

Comment: I have lost all my installed packages after using pyenv. Is there a way to map my old dist-packages to the new python?

Answer (score 0):

`trusty-updates` release channel of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS provides **Python 3.4.3** (if you want simply newer version of Python than 3.4.0, not exactly 3.4.2).

You can enable `trusty-updates` in `Software & Updates` settings (they should be enabled by default):

[image]