# IDLE and PyCharm using Python 3.4.0 when 3.4.1 installed?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center, python, idle-python

I recently visited the Python site, and noticed that a new version, 3.4.1 had come out.
My Ubuntu 14.04 had 3.4.0, so I downloaded 3.4.1 and installed it.
When I open IDLE, it showed 3.4.0, but when I open a terminal and type `python3`, it shows 3.4.1.
I re-installed IDLE, then I searched for IDLE 3.4.1 Ubuntu, but I did not get anything.
I got Debian's packages site for the `IDLE 3.4.1.deb` file, so I downloaded that.
I installed it, and yet IDLE showed 3.4.0, when I checked the Ubuntu Software Center, and it showed idle-python3.4 3.4.1-6 version so it should work.

Update:
Looks like typing `python34` and `python340` just returns errors.
But typing `python3` gives me python 3.4.1 and of course `python` gives me python 2.7.
It is like python 3.4.0 is not there but IDLE is still able to somehow access to it

In PyCharm there is an option to choose which Python Interpreter you want to use, I get 2.7 and 3.4.0 there.

Comment: Did you uninstall the old version of Python (3.4.0) before you installed the new version (3.4.1)?

Comment: Python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 comes pre installed with the Operating System, it would not be wise to uninstall it because the system may be using it for various internal tasks. You can just install an additional version for your needs.

Comment: No, I did not remove python 3.4.0 but Stef K is correct. If I remove python 3.4.0 now, I mean after installing 3.4.1, will anything bad occur? Oh and I edited my question, I forgot to mention something. Please read it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/474108/ubuntu-14-04-lts-and-python-3-4-1 Intalling 3.4.1 writes over the link to 3.4.0

Comment: @Tim I am talking about the selection available, not about the link as that has been overwritten.

Comment: @IAnsari It hasn't been overwritten - see my answer ▼...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the folder `/usr/bin/` you will have files similar to this (the ones in bold are symbolic links).

**`python`**

**`python2`**

`python2.7`

**`python3`**

`python3.4`

**`python3.4-config`**

`python3.4m`

**`python3.4m-config`**

**`python3-config`**

**`python3m`**

**`python3m-config`**

So the command `python 3` is actually a link to the executable `python3.4`.

When you "upgrade" to `3.4.1` it doesn't atually remove 3.4.0. Try running `/usr/bin/python3.4` and `/usr/bin/python3`

The new install is somewhere different: `/usr/local/bin/python3`

That link goes to the new executable `/usr/local/bin/python3.4`, which is `3.4.1`.

That's why running `python3` gives you `3.4.1` in terminal, but idle3 is `3.4.0`. (They "look" in the respective places first).

So PyCharm is (presumably) looking in `/usr/bin/` first, so it doesn't see the `3.4.1`. Try adding a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/` named `python341` (or similar) that links to `/usr/local/bin/python3.4`

Comment: Tim how do you create the symbolic link?

Comment: I have found a way to manually choose a symbolic link as an interpreter in PyCharm.

Comment: it is not nautlus by the way. (I am an intermediate Ubuntu user, BTW :) ). It is nautilus

Comment: Sorry for that :)