# How do I install python 3.5.2?

Tags: 16.04, python3, python-2.7

It's my first time using ubuntu so I don't know how to use it very well yet...
How can i install python 3.5.2 ? It has already the version 2.7.12 .
My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (desktop).

Comment: just fyi, you probably already have python 3.5.1 (though not 3.5.2). Try opening a terminal & typing `python3`...

Comment: @Zanna it shows `3.5.1-3` on my system

Comment: you're right , i typed python 3 and showed this "Python 3.5.1+ "

however how can I update to the 3.5.2 version? i will start learning with a book that has that version...

Comment: the differences between python 2* and python 3* are big, you would notice a lot of difference in behaviour. But python 3.5.1+ and 3.5.2 are very similar and will behave almost the same. It's possible to compile the newer version from source, but using repo versions is generally recommended - that way package management will look after its dependencies and keep the app updated. My advice would be just dive in with the book using python3 (and IDLE 3 (to get it type in a terminal `sudo apt install idle3`) if the book recommends)

Comment: @RuiMiranda If you are new to Ubuntu/Linux and Python, don't bother trying to upgrade your Python 3 from 3.5.1 to 3.5.2 by compiling from source; you will only end up coming back to this site with even more questions that distract you from learning Python.

Comment: See [Is it possible to install Python 3.x in 14.04 LTS, or upgrade from Python 2.7.6 to 2.7.8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517006/is-it-possible-to-install-python-3-x-in-14-04-lts-or-upgrade-from-python-2-7-6/517007). But I join Zanna and edwinksl in advising that you use the version of Python 3 provided by your system for learning Python 3 programming unless you have a specific and compelling reason to use a different version.

Answer (score 8):

Basic process:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3
```

If you want a very specific version:

```
sudo apt-cache show python3
sudo apt-get install python3=3.5.1*
```

Comment: I get `E: Unable to locate package python3=` when I run your suggested command. Are you show that is right?

Comment: It's a single equals sign to denote a specific version.

Comment: @ThomasWard who is that comment addressed at?

Comment: this still doesn't work for me I get `E: Version '3.5.1*' for 'python3' was not found`

Comment: @CharlieParker, originally I'd written "python3==3.5.1*", which is why you got that "unable to locate" error. Note the two equals signs.

Comment: @tedder42 ah ok. I've ran it with one equal sign and the star too and it still doesn't work. Does it work for you? Not sure if the fact I'm inside a docker container makes any difference but its unable to find the python version. What am I suppose to see with `apt-cache show python3`?

Comment: This doesn't work. `Version '3.5.1*' for 'python3' was not found`

Comment: @JibuJames what's available has changed in two years. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Right now it looks like two `3.6.*` versions are installable from a generic 18.04 install, and `3.5.1-3` is available from a generic 16.04 install.

Comment: this does not work for Ubuntu 16.04, since the python version in the repos is 3.5.1

Answer (score 6):

As you must have already noticed that Ubuntu 16.04 has 'python 2.7.12' by default.
To check the default python version, run below line

```
   $ python -V
```

it should return 'Python 2.7.12'

It is recommended that we don't try to modify/uninstall this default package of python because there could be many other system files/applications depending on it, and it might create some unexpected errors or issues if we uninstall this default python package.

So, to use the latest version of python, it would be better to go for creating a virtual environment ('virtualenv'). This is a module inside python which facilitates us to use multiple python versions on the same system.

Step-1: First install python3 -

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3
```

Step-2: Now install 'virtualenv'-

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

Step-3: Now set the path of virtualenv to your desired directory.
lets first create a desired directory-

```
$ mkdir MYENV
```

it will create a folder in the current directory with the name 'MYENV'

Step-4: set the path of virtualenv to the created(desired) directory-

```
$ sudo virtualenv -p python3 MYENV
```

Step-5: Activate the virtualenv

```
$ source MYENV/bin/activate
```

done..
you should be able to get (MYENV) as prefix in the terminal command line.
Now run below command

```
$ python -V
```

it should return 'python 3.5.2'

Comment: This is awesome ans amongst of all the ans given SE sites.

Comment: Few remarks : 1/ No need to install python3, it's already available in Ubuntu 16.04. 2/ No need to install virtualenv. You can spin up a virtualenv using the recommanded `python3 -m venv MYVENV`. So basically all you have to type is `python3 -m venv MYVENV && source MYVENV/bin/activate`