# Update default python3 version from 3.2.3 to 3.3.x version in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python3

I would like to upgrade my `python3` version from `3.2.3` to `3.3.x` version. I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`

Referred this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474108/ubuntu-14-04-lts-and-python-3-4-2). Is it the same procedure to upgrade the python version?

If so, then what must be run instead of `sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4`?

I have a doubt in the procedure because it is updating in same version line `3.4.x`. Please refer and say so as to avoid further problems.

**Edit 1:** Also referred this link [How do I install python 3.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3) but did not help me.

Comment: I tried it out but does not replace the default version

Comment: There are multiple answers there. Which ones did you try?

Comment: All the answers are to install the python3.3 version in `virtualenv` and not in default location. Most of the answers are similar and tried the top 3.

Comment: What? The very first answer is to install python3.3 from the Deadsnakes PPA, which installs `/usr/bin/python3.3`, not in a virtualenv. Please read through.

Comment: I did not raise the question without trying it @muru. It did not replace the default version

Comment: You want `/usr/bin/python3` to be Python 3.3? Then just do `sudo ln /usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python3` after using the deadsnakes PPA.

Comment: does `ln` command not cause any problems?

Comment: You're try to make Python 3.3 *the default*. I'd be more worried about that than `ln`.

Comment: does updating to 3.3 make any issues?

Comment: Who knows? Remember that all the Ubuntu packages that use Python 3 are tested with Python 3.2, not 3.3. There's no telling what might happen. *That* is why people suggest virtualenv - it's a bad idea to mess with `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: I am trying to make it due to the following question @muru [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/783800/errors-in-installing-virtualenv-after-installing-to-python-3-3-0-also)

Answer (score 3):

While relatively little in 12.04's core system relies on Python 3, I would *always* and in the strongest terms recommend that you **leave the default Python environments to themselves**.

That is to say:

- Don't mess with the `/usr/bin/python{,2,3}` etc links.
- Don't `sudo {pip install,easy_install}` anything into the system's site packages.

This is contrary to what you say you want to do but seriously, given you don't already know how to do this, you're a very long way away from knowing how to fix a broken system.

In your case, I'd recommend compiling your version of Python (in your home directory or even in `/opt/`) and then creating a virtualenv (venv) from that. 
Inside the virtualenv, `python` (and everything that uses it) will refer to the version of Python used during the creation of that environment.

```
cd project_directory
/path/to/python -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install whatever
```

Comment: So according to the answer and the comments, I avoid the updation of the python3 version. But what shall I do to install pip3?

Comment: You can [run this script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) using the specific version of python to get pip for it, and then run this version and execute pip as a module, like `/opt/python3/bin/python3.5 -m pip install emojitations`. More info at [pypa.io](https://pypa.io).

Comment: to avoid further problems, I am not going to update the python3 version and also going to skip installing pip3. No more options.